# If any cell contain symbol do calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif

I have an issue with Excel 2010 that I would like help with. It must be done with a formula and not a VBA macro.

I have a top row where I want to check if every cell contain a specified symbol. If it does contain it, then I want to do check if a cell in the same column contain another specified symbol
. 
Like here in this example. If I want to count all the cells that contain "X" that have the "@" symbol after the company name in the same column; how would I go about that?

```
Company X@     Company Yx      Company Z@     Company Z     Company Y@
X              X               X              X
```

So this should count the "X"s and give me the integer 2, as there are 3 company's that have the "@" symbol but only two of them contain an "X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple COUNTIFS with a wildcard seems to work.

```
=COUNTIFS(A$1:E$1, "*@*", A2:E2, "X")
```

[image]

Comment: btw, that is an open wildcard (i.e. before and after). If the `@` symbol is always '*after the company name*' then it could be `"*@"`.

Comment: Thanks, that works good! 

A follow up question! Is it possible to do a sum of several countifs? Like if I got multiple separate rows that I want to do the exact same thing on; and then add them all together?

Comment: re: '*Is it possible to do a sum of several countifs*' - Yes, but that would be a new question will different sample data and a different narrative describing the situation and expected results.